# JVM DLL not found on Mac ARM when running jpype

Tags: python, java, jpype

I am trying to use the python package JPype which is installed on my anaconda virtual environment.

I have installed JDK 21 but I keep getting an error when I try to use JPype. The error is:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] JVM DLL not found: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib
```

I have been trying to trouble shoot for a while and I have so far:

1. Checked that the architecture is the same as python on the Java installation
2. Checked my Java Home is set up

But I still cannot get it to work. Please let know if you can help.